# Dynamically extract two or three text spaces

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with some products, which I want to separate by the content of the first two or three words according to their content:

```
WITH 
test_data AS
(
SELECT 'GALLETAS SALADAS' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS DE LECHE' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS CRACKER CON SABOR A MANTEQUILLA' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS INTEGRALES CON AVENA' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS WAFER CON CREMA DE CHOCOLATE' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS WAFER CON CREMA SABOR A VAINILLA' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS DE MANTEQUILLA' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS SALTIN' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS DE CHOCOLATE CON CREMA SABOR A VAINILLA' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS CON SABOR A VAINILLA' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS CON CREMA SABOR A FRESA' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'BARQUILLOS SABOR A CHOCOLATE CON CREMA SABOR A LECHE' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'PASTEL CON CREMA SABOR A VAINILLA' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS DE LECHE CON CREMA DE AVENA Y SABOR A LECHE' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS CON CREMA SABOR A YOGURT FRESA' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS CON AVENA Y CALCIO' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'BARQUILLOS CON CREMA SABOR A FRESA' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'BARQUILLOS RELLENOS CON CREMA DE CHOCOLATE Y AVELLANA' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS MINI WAFER CUBIERTAS CON SABOR A CHOCOLATE' AS product FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'GALLETAS WAFER CON CREMA SABOR A AREQUIPE (DULCE DE LECHE)' AS product FROM dual
)SELECT CASE 
        WHEN (INSTR(test_data.product,' ',1,2) = 0) THEN
             substr(test_data.product, 1, LENGTH(test_data.product))  
        WHEN (INSTR(test_data.product,' ',1, 3) = 0) THEN
             substr(test_data.product, 1, INSTR(test_data.product,' ',1, 2))
        ELSE substr(test_data.product, 1, INSTR(test_data.product,' ',1, 3))
       END
FROM   test_data;
```

**expected result:**

```
GALLETAS SALADAS
GALLETAS DE LECHE
GALLETAS CRACKER
GALLETAS INTEGRALES
GALLETAS WAFER
GALLETAS WAFER
GALLETAS DE MANTEQUILLA
GALLETAS SALTIN
GALLETAS DE CHOCOLATE
GALLETAS CON SABOR
GALLETAS CON CREMA
BARQUILLOS SABOR
PASTEL CON CREMA
GALLETAS DE LECHE
GALLETAS CON CREMA
GALLETAS CON AVENA
BARQUILLOS CON CREMA
BARQUILLOS RELLENOS
GALLETAS MINI WAFER
GALLETAS WAFER
```

I am modifying it to use keywords in the intermediate word `DE` or`CON`, also evaluating the size, but I do not know before complicating myself and making a lot of lines if there is any way to simplify it.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=292ca4dc48933306858d177cbfbfe1b1)

Comment: There is one conversion that does not seem to follow the same logic: `'BARQUILLOS SABOR A CHOCOLATE CON CREMA SABOR A LECHE'` to `'BARQUILLOS'`. This one does not follow the rule you explained (other do)

Comment: @GMB excuse me, it went wrong

Comment: Also I think that `'GALLETAS MINI WAFER CUBIERTAS CON SABOR A CHOCOLATE'` should be turned to `'GALLETAS MINI WAFER'` instead of `'GALLETAS MIN'`.

Comment: @GMB Exactly, you are absolutely right, I have thought with this regular expression `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(test_data.product, '\s{1,}CO|\s{1,}CON|\s{1,}DE|\s{1,}[A-Za-z0-9]$', '')
  FROM DUAL;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that implements the logic that you described, using Oracle regexp functions. Since the Oracle regexp engine does not support lookaheads, I think that two function calls are needed:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(product, '^(\w+\s*\w*\s*\w*)'),
    '(\s+DE$)|(\s+CON$)',
    ''
)
```

Explanation:

- the inner `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` returns the first three words of the products (with the second and third word being optional)
- the outer `REGEXP_REPLACE()` supresses words `'DE'` or `'CON'` at the end of the remaining string, if they exists

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=72d558f40923cdb5c99c3dd8d5ee2d91)**:

```
| SHORT_PRODUCT           |
| :---------------------- |
| GALLETAS SALADAS        |
| GALLETAS DE LECHE       |
| GALLETAS CRACKER        |
| GALLETAS INTEGRALES     |
| GALLETAS WAFER          |
| GALLETAS WAFER          |
| GALLETAS DE MANTEQUILLA |
| GALLETAS SALTIN         |
| GALLETAS DE CHOCOLATE   |
| GALLETAS CON SABOR      |
| GALLETAS CON CREMA      |
| BARQUILLOS SABOR A      |
| PASTEL CON CREMA        |
| GALLETAS DE LECHE       |
| GALLETAS CON CREMA      |
| GALLETAS CON AVENA      |
| BARQUILLOS CON CREMA    |
| BARQUILLOS RELLENOS     |
| GALLETAS MINI WAFER     |
| GALLETAS WAFER          |
```

As commented, it seems like there are a few discrepancies if your expected result.